# call classname as function inside class

Tags: php, oop, php-7.2

I am moving a website from PHP5.5 to PHP7.2 and having some issues with the OOP functions.

```
class messageStack extends tableBox {
    function __construct() {
      global $messageToStack;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    function output($class) {
     $this->table_data_parameters = 'class="messageBox"';

    $output = array();
    for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($this->messages); $i<$n; $i++) {
      if ($this->messages[$i]['class'] == $class) {
        $output[] = $this->messages[$i];
      }
   }
   return $this->tableBox($output);
  }
}
```

and getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method messageStack::tableBox() in classes\message_stack.php on line 74
```

Pardon me if something wrong. Any guidance will be appreciated

Comment: Function tableBox isn't defined.

Comment: yeah... As I am noob to OOP so my question is that return **tableBox** should be a function or classname because classname is same **tableBox**??

Comment: There has to be a function named tableBox, either in the class or the parent class.

Comment: If the function name is the same as the class name, this used to be the constructor (`__construct`) method, but this was changed at some point (can't remember when).  So it may be worth seeing if that does what you would expect.